# Cannot choose between the following variants of project :MrcosClient: - debugRuntimeElements - releaseRuntimeElements

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

**I can't solve this error, I already downloaded sdk 25 in my android studio 4.0 but still I got this error**

Cannot choose between the following variants of project :MrcosClient:

- debugRuntimeElements
- releaseRuntimeElements
  All of them match the consumer attributes:
- Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability mrcos-mobile-repo:MrcosClient:unspecified:

  - Unmatched attributes:

    - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
    - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
    - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
- Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability mrcos-mobile-repo:MrcosClient:unspecified:

  - Unmatched attributes:

    - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
    - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
    - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.

Here are my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mrcos.pmti.biz.mrcos"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "mrcos_app_v$versionName")

        ndk {
            moduleName "libmrcosclientndk"
        }
        packagingOptions {
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['lib']
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {


        prod {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_VERSION_NAME', '"2.0"'
            buildConfigField "long", "TIMESTAMP", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

}

greendao {
    targetGenDir 'src/main/java'
}


dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/wisepadapi-android-2.0.0.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
   
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1"
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile project(':MrcosClient')

    //Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'

    //RxJava
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0'
    compile files('libs/platform_extension.jar')

    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'


    //Currency
    compile 'com.github.BlacKCaT27:CurrencyEditText:v1.4.4'

    //Dialog
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.5'
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'


    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6" //or v. 1.16.2 in your case.
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
    compile files('libs/jsch-0.1.54.jar')

}





apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            moduleName "mrcosclientndk"


        }
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs =['libs']
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude "lib/arm64/libstlport_shared.so"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar')

    compile files('libs/pmti-ldonios-lib.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
    //clearableeditext
    compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:2.9.6'
    //retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.1'
    //RxAndroid
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    //dagger
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1"
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile files('libs/mrcoscodec.jar')
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'

    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6" //or v. 1.16.2 in your case.



}



buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
       
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: try removing `implementation project(':SomeModule')`, if in this case the app is running without this error then try to add `path` and `configuration` in the above sample code. In my case problem was in that I was trying include and load wrong module in my base app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a missingDimensionStrategy in the gradle config of your module.
This will provide a default value for a flavor that is not set in your module. For further informations how to the missingDimensionStrategy with examples i'll refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/BaseFlavor#missingdimensionstrategy)